# Modifying operating system environment variables from Python

Tags: python

I'm using Tesseract OCR and everytime I run a new session it asks for setting the TESSDATA_PREFIX variable, 
I do so by running the command `export TESSDATA_PREFIX="PATH_TO_FILES"`
How can I do it inside the python script i'm running ? 

Thanks !

Comment: it depends on how you run the session. Do you use `subprocess`?

Comment: Why, does `import os; os.environ['TESSDATA_PREFIX'] = "PATH_TO_FILES"` not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
 import os
 os.putenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX", "PATH_TO_FILES")
```

More info

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.putenv

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding to your python:

```
import os
os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = "PATH_TO_FILES"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using os module to set environment variable:

setting:

```
os.environ['TESSDATA_PREFIX'] = "PATH_TO_FILES"
```

getting:

```
   pat_to_files = os.environ['TESSDATA_PREFIX']
```

Such variable will be accessible from the python code but it may not remain accessible for other programs when your python code quits.

If your goal is to set env variable for other program then you could try this recipe:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/159462-how-to-set-environment-variables/